# SQL Using Ungrouped Columns in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a `GROUP BY` Query which appears to use non-aggregated data *not* in the `GROUP BY` clause, which I thought would not work.

I was asked to write a query which converted the following data:

```
| item | type | cost | category |
|------|------|------|----------|
| 1    | X    | 10   | A        |
| 1    | Y    | 20   | A        |
| 2    | X    | 30   | B        |
| 2    | Y    | 40   | B        |
| 3    | X    | 50   | C        |
| 3    | Y    | 60   | C        |
| 4    | X    | 70   | D        |
| 4    | Y    | 80   | D        |
```

into this:

```
| item | x  | y  | category |
|------|----|----|----------|
| 1    | 10 | 20 | A        |
| 2    | 30 | 40 | B        |
| 3    | 50 | 60 | C        |
| 4    | 70 | 80 | D        |
```

Note:

- The incoming data is clearly not normalised
- The `item` is meant to be unique, but it is repeated for each `type` value
- The `category` is the same for rows of the same `item`

I ended up with the following solution:

```
SELECT
    item,
    sum(CASE WHEN type='X' THEN cost END) as X,
    sum(CASE WHEN type='Y' THEN cost END) as Y,
    category
FROM data
GROUP BY item,category;
```

What surprised me is that it worked. What surprised me more is that it works for PostgreSQL, MariaDB (ANSI Mode), Microsoft SQL and SQLite.

Note:
- I have included `category` in the `GROUP BY` simply to allow it to appear in the `SELECT` clause.
- I have used the `sum()` function, even though there will only be one value, also simply to included it in the `SELECT` clause.

I *thought* I would not be able to use `type` column in the `SELECT` column because it is not in the `GROUP BY` and it is not aggregated. Indeed, if I try to select it by itself, the query will fail.

The question is, how is it that I can use the `type` column with the `CASE` operator, when I can’t use it by itself?

Comment: It is because you have used 'type' column inside SUM().

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, that explains it — it didn’t occur to me that including the data inside an aggregate also made it an aggregate. I was aware that PostgreSQL has a more straightforward syntax, but I was exploring this particular case. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can clean this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of the "ungrouped" columns is perfectly fine.

The rule is: "Every expression in the SELECT list must either be an aggregat function or it must part of the GROUP BY".

The column `type` **is** used inside an aggregate. `sum(CASE WHEN type='X' THEN cost END) as X` is not really different to `sum(cost)` or `max(type)`.

This becomes more obvious if you use the standard SQL `filter` option:

```
sum(CASE WHEN type='X' THEN cost END)
```

is the same as:

```
sum(cost) filter (where type = 'X')
```

However only very few DBMS support this standard.

Comment: Thanks again. It makes sense now.